# mySQL : How to perform calculations over different tables

Tags: mysql

So i have a table which lists salaries of all employees. Another table which lists the departments and another table which lists the department employees. The common column between table **salaries** and table **dep_emp** is *emp_no*. The common column between table **departments** and **dep_emp** is *dept_no*. I need to obtain the current average salary of a particular department

```sql
SELECT COUNT(emp_no)
FROM dept_emp
WHERE dept_no='d001'; -- this gives me the count that i need to divide the salary by
```

But how would i make the connection between this particular table and the other? Should I do a INNER JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need joins between the tables using the fields you mentioned, but you can use the avg() function to get the average:

```
select d.dept_no, avg(e.salary)
from departments d
left join dept_emp de on d.dept_no=de.dept_no
left join employees e on de.emp_no=e.emp_no
group by d.tept_no
```

Whether you use left or inner join depends on your exact requirements.